# Do I have to duplicate plugin configuration in Maven profiles?

Tags: java, maven, rpm, maven-profiles

I'm using [rpm-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/) to create an RPM that installs my java project.  I need to build RPMs for both CentOS 5 and CentOS 7.  I'm already using profiles to set properties that contain the names of some RPM dependencies that differ between the two, then referencing those properties in the rpm plugin.

I now need to also change what files the RPM puts in place based on the cent5 vs cent7 profiles (cent 5 still uses init scripts, cent 7 has gone to unit files with systemd).  I can't think of an easy way to do that by setting properties, I need to include different file mappings in each.  Do I need to duplicate my (long) RPM plugin configuration in two profiles to get the changes?  That feels dangerous because the plugin configuration is long, and duplication will inevitably lead to developers making future changes in one and missing the other.  Is there a way to just add to the plugin configuration with the profile?

What is the best way to manage a small change of a complicated plugin configuration across maven profiles?

Comment: What about using Maven's [aggregation (with sub-modules)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v) **and** [inheritance (with a parent POM)](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit). See  [Maven and Profiles: ...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33291639/1744774), for instance.

Comment: After reading through these links, I believe I've been convinced that I'm falling into the trap of trying to use profiles for everything instead of using the strategies that split across multiple POMs.  I think the inheritance mechanism will get me what I need.  Common build steps in one, inherited by two more POMs specific to the target OSs.  I will have the RPM plugin defined in both with just minor changes to them, but that's okay to buy me a scalable solution when more differences inevitably surface.  If you posted this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Maven's [aggregation (with sub-modules)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v):

> *Inheritance and aggregation create a nice dynamic to control builds through a single, high-level POM. You will often see projects that are both parents and aggregators.*

**and** [inheritance (with a parent POM)](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit):

> *A parent project is one that passes its values to its children. A multimodule project simply manages a group of other subprojects or modules.*

See also this [answer to *Maven and Profiles: ...*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33291639/1744774).